# Client side text file validation and upload

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, fileapi

I'm trying to upload a file into the browser and access it using JavaScript.  Is this possible?  I've looked around and it seems that you can accomplish this using flash.  I was trying to see if there was an HTML5/pure JavaScript solution.

I'm trying to upload a CSV file (each row contains a possible database entry) and validate it on the fly using javascript.  If it passes validation, then I'll send a POST to the server to create the items.

Answer (score 10):

This is possible. [MDN offers a detailed explanation on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications).

The following is a basic method to read a text file using the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) API:
  **http://jsfiddle.net/tGpDG/**

```
<input type="file" id="file_upload">
<script>
var input_file = document.getElementById('file_upload');
input_file.onchange = function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    // Do something with the FileReader object
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function(ev) {
        // Show content  (ev.target === reader)
        alert(ev.target.result);
    };
    // Read as plain text
    reader.readAsText(file);  
};
</script>
```

Comment: what if i want to read file and throw exception if content is not proper? all these are asynch calls rite? in short how to throw an exception from within function for reader.onload?

Comment: in above case how will that user throw error/exception if his csv is improper?

Comment: @VJD Since the code is asynchronous, you cannot break the execution of the caller by "throwing". If you've structured your code well, either use two callbacks (one for success, one for failure), or use multiple arguments for success/failure, e.g. `function callback(result, error) { if (error) .... }`. If you don't like long callback chains in your code, look up promises.